# How to set a fixed order for each group of attributes under attribute set name?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set, custom-attributes

I have several attributes.

Some of them have been specifically created for this store. In Catalog --> attributes --> **manage set of attributes** they are grouped under a custom group called "**technical data**"

I have several set of attributes (one for every product categories) and they have different attributes under the group "**technical data**"

This attributes are showed in **alphabetical order** on the frontend in page product if their field are compiled.

I would like to change the order to present them using a **customized order**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.go to your attribute set, you will see all attributes and the groups they are under in your techincal group try to move the attributes around by drag and drop.Hit the button save attribute set and check them again on your products.
You can just drag and drop and change the order of them under groups and then you have them in a customized order.